# Application crash using Google maps during map fragment view creation

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

It happens when `SupportMapFragment` is used, specifically when transaction commited. It started to happen recently on specific device (maybe after update of google play services, couldn't trace it).

Crashes are consistent through all previous app version that was already tested and there was no changes in used libs versions or build tools.

Environment details:

- Device LG G3 D855
- Google play services lib version 8.4.0
- Google play services on device version 9.6.83
- Android version 5.0
- Build tools version "23.0.2"

Crash stack trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
                                                                    at maps.G.a.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at maps.V.N.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at maps.D.e.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at maps.D.p.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at maps.ad.ae.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at maps.ad.t.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at maps.ad.M.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at ul.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:107)
                                                                    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$zza$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$4.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5274)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
```

Has anyone else witnessed this? If so, were you able to solve it? 
In addition to the info provided in the link,  I'm using the `MultiDex` library which I know sometimes causes weird behaviors.

Due to NDA cannot provide any application specific information.

Comment: try it on different device and check if it crashes on all phones

Comment: It doesn't always happen, only sometimes but on different devices with Android 4 and 5.

Answer (score 1):

```
<activity android:name="com.bison.activities.YourActivity"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Try adding this to you activity in manifest.
If it helps study the hardware acceleration in google documentation